# How to prove I live in a specific address?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, common-law

https://www.flhsmv.gov/ddl/address.html

I need to provide proof of address for the DMV, but the process can be difficult because:

I live with someone else; I do not pay rent/utilities; and they will not assist in the process.

The Florida DMV asks that you need two of these for proof of address, which can be tough:

> 1.Deed, mortgage, monthly mortgage statement, mortgage payment booklet or residential rental/lease agreement

Can't -- don't have any of the above because I'm not paying rent nor am I a homeowner.

> Florida Voter Registration Card

Cannot be obtained until after proof of address was obtained initially for the relevant application I'm trying to go for now.

> Florida Vehicle Registration or Title

Don't own a car/vehicle.

> Florida Boat Registration or Title

Don't own a boat.

> Statements (Certification of Address Form) Customers with one proof of
>   residential address may self-certify using the Certification of
>   Address form as the second proof of residential address document

A caveat also states that this must be accompanied by the person you live with's signature and/or their actual presence, which I explained that they refuse to do so.

> A utility hook up or work order

Don't pay bills.

> Automobile Payment Booklet

Don't own a car.

> Selective Service Card

This is only for males.

> Medical or health card

I have one, but it doesn't have my address on it so it's not proof, according to the DMV.

> Medical bill

Never had one.

> Homeowner's insurance policy or bill

Not a homeowner.

> Automobile insurance policy or bill

Don't own a car.

> Educational institution transcript forms

Have no such things and cannot obtain any since I am not in the public school system as of now.

> Professional license issued by a government agency in the U.S.

Caveat -- must be currently valid and up-to-date and it isn't, and this is what I am initially trying to get renewed in the first place.

> W-2 form or 1099 form

I am self-employed, so neither of those can work for me.

> Form DS2019, Certificate of Eligibility for Exchange Visitor (J-1)
>   status

This is only for Visa/resident/non-citizen card holders.

> A letter from a homeless shelter, transitional service provider, or a
>   half-way house verifying that the customer resides at the shelter
>   address

I'm not homeless and none else applies.

> Utility bills

Don't pay utilities.

> Mail from financial institutions; including checking, savings, credit
>   card statements or investment account statements

I haven't been issued paper mail by a bank since years -- everything digital.
I also don't have credit card debt because I've never had a credit card and have no other "investment statements."

> Mail from Federal, State, County or City government agencies
>   (including city and county agencies)

If I was getting federal mail I'd be worried -- it's never happened.

> Personal mail that does not list the recipient as “occupant”. Example: Magazines, journals, etc.

I throw all that junk out, or hardly get it in the first place.

> Transients - Sexual Offender/Predator/Career Offender:  �����- FDLE
>   Registration form completed by local sheriff's department

Doesn't apply -- I get plenty of sex without offending anyone.

What can I do? I was thinking of writing a certificate or affidavit stating that I admit under some penalty of perjury that I live in the address -- however, I can almost bet they'll still want the person who pays rent to sign, so I'm out of options.

I suppose I could get a credit card and rack up a bill and get statements, but that would probably take at least a month and I need this certificate very soon.

Comment: You don't get any of that stuff? Wowz.

Comment: FL doesn't let you use a IRS 1040 or a state tax return with your SSN and mailing address as proof? I know several other states do -- it may work there as well. You're self employed, but you should still be paying income tax on the self-employment earnings/losses. It might be worth asking if federal and/or state returns will work.

Comment: if you dont have any of it you dont exist. hence you dont need a driver license

Comment: How soon do you need the driver's license/state ID, and how likely is the primary occupant of your residence to timely give it, or any other mail addressed to you, to you if it does arrive? (If there's a serious danger that said person would confiscate a license or other correspondence upon arrival, maybe you should check into a homeless shelter for a week, or at least find another place to live while you're going through this process.)

Comment: @tpg2114 - A tax return as such is created by the person who fills it out, so it doesn't really prove that the person can actually receive mail at that address. However, it seems that just about any correspondence _from_ a tax authority would fit well within the kinds of documents on the State of Florida's list, especially since it's a "fluid list" per the note at the bottom.

Comment: @david In GA at least, a state or federal tax return from within the last two years is sufficient to prove both residential address and SSN. My guess is they can verify the copy you brought in against a copy on record with the state. But one couldn't bring in a 2015 tax return yet because they haven't been processed and made official.

Comment: I've never seen a bank issue a statement without having *some* address on it, even if they email your statement. What address is on your bank account? My bank lets me download PDF statements that look just like a paper statement.

Comment: **Catch-22** situation?

Comment: Well before all that, I need proof you exist.

Comment: Is your name on the mailbox? Do you receive mail addressed to you?

Comment: It may seem bizarre but perhaps you could talk to the local police and ask them to help verify your address somehow. Seems to me (IANAL) that if there is an official police report of some kind showing you as a resident at that address that should be sufficient proof. Of course what you do not want to do is offend your "landlord" in the process.

Comment: What about the person who DOES do those things? Can the person who pays the bills say "I own this home, and EyeSi definitely resides at 123 State St. Without paying bills. Ever. The jerk. With all that money he's saving, why doesn't he buy us a boat?"

Comment: @corsiKa Yes they can, but the OP clearly states that they won't.  (Which seems odd, but families can be like that sometimes - I assume "family" because non-family would just throw the OP out.)

Comment: So, 3+ years have gone by, and I'm curious what ended up happening? Was there something stopping you from printing out a digital bank statement? (Don't say you don't have a printer -- you can do this at any commercial printing service, e.g. a FedEx location).

Comment: That seems like such an US-specific problem. Most European countries have [resident registration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_registration), which exists precisely so you can prove where you live.

Answer (score 45):

> Mail from financial institutions; including checking, savings, credit card statements or investment account statements

Pay a bank or credit card company $2 or some other nominal fee to have them send you a physical copy of a statement.

Comment: This looks like the best option. Even if you opt for paperless statements you can request the bank to send you a paper one, exactly because one may need a proof of funds or address. In some cases, the institution or person requesting the proof of address will accept a PDF statement, which you can download from your online banking.

Comment: Yep, why not just print an online copy. I assume you have access to the internet and a printer.

Comment: The requirement is literally "Mail" from them.  They may accept a printed online copy with your address in practice, but it does not technically meet the requirement, does not have a postmark, etc...

Comment: Printed copy of your online bill are not generally accepted as you can easily forge or manipulate it. However in some cases I've been able to provide the original PDF generated by the bank sending it via email.

Answer (score 29):

Request a [Social Security statement](https://www.socialsecurity.gov/hlp/global/hlp-statement-7004-revi.htm).  Get a library card.  Write a letter to your senator or representative or a local government office that requires a response.  Order something online.  Register to vote (you can do this with the last 4 digits of your social security number and [without having to prove your address](http://dos.myflorida.com/media/693757/dsde39.pdf)).

Comment: Write a letter to the DMV asking them how to prove your address. They will reply, and you have your proof - I wonder whether they still need a second proof.

Comment: @Alexander trolling level 10

Comment: order stamps.  It will be mail from a government agency.  Had a co-worker do this after moving.

Comment: The first one, for sure.  Social security statement should be coming _anyway_ - that's federal mail.

Comment: @Joe but the SS statement only comes automatically once every five years.

Answer (score 23):

> Personal mail that does not list the recipient as “occupant”. Example: Magazines, journals, etc.

Get some friends to write to you.

Comment: Or better yet, write a letter to yourself.

Answer (score 5):

write a letter to yourself and receive it.